# Multiple temporary/local task branches in MQ/Mercurial?

Tags: version-control, mercurial, mercurial-queue

I've read Steve Losh's [article](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2010/08/a-git-users-guide-to-mercurial-queues/#multiple-patch-queues) about using MQ's qqueues command to create multiple queues.  This has the potential to get me closer to my personal take on Nirvana (namely, Git local branches), because I can keep changes related to separate features isolated from one another, I can roll the local changes into a single patch for release upstream, and I can delete the queues when I'm done with them.  Awesome.  Except I can't get it to work. I create the first queue using hg qqueue -c feature1, apply a patch to it using qrefresh, and then try to create a new queue. When I do I get an error:

```
~/src/mqtest$ hgl
@  55ae767d5eae  Adding feature1file  2013-04-29 15:32 -0500 Jon Blackburn default addFeature1file qbase qtip tip
|
o  58b232e9b36a  Initial commit on default.  2013-04-29 15:27 -0500 Jon Blackburn default qparent

~/src/mqtest$ hg qapplied 
addFeature1file
~/src/mqtest$ hg qq
feature1 (active)
patches
~/src/mqtest$ hg qq -c feature2
abort: new queue created, but cannot make active as patches are applied
~/src/mqtest$
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

P.S. @Lazy Badger indicated some skepticism about whether I need to pop -a in order to change queues.  I'll say first that it's the only thing I've found that works.  Also, from mq.py:

```
def _setactive(name):
    if q.applied:
    raise util.Abort(_('new queue created, but cannot make active '
                           'as patches are applied'))
    _setactivenocheck(name)
```

If there's a more appropriate way to switch to a new queue while I've got patches applied to the one I'm on, I'd love to hear it.  With this solution the workflow would be 1) pop -a; 2) qqueue feature2; 3) optionally, push -a (if feature2 has some patches already). It's not clear to me *why* mq requires that no patches be applied to the queue you're leaving. I can't come up with a scenario in my head where that's useful. If my existing queue must be empty for me to leave it, then perhaps offer a flag to tell mq to pop -a my current queue (and push -a my target queue)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have one patch from feature1 applied, thus - qqueue can't switch to second queue after it's creation. From `hg help qqueue`

> To create a new queue, use -c/--create. The queue is automatically made active, **except in the case where there are applied patches from the currently active queue** in the repository.

You have to:

- unapply patch before creating new queue

or

- switch to *created* queue by hand

Comment: Thanks, Badger. I do have to say the docs are lacking here.  Why do I have to run hg qpop -a on my current queue in order to move to another? Just seems odd to me.  But I'm an accommodater, that's what I am.

Comment: @JonathanBlackburn - I'm not sure about **mandatory** qpop -a for switching to *existing* queue with `hg qqueue <NAME>`

Comment: Yes, switching to an existing queue also requires that your current queue be empty.

Comment: @JonathanBlackburn - add alias for *your* habits, which will combine qrefresh+qpop+qqueue?